# Why is toJSON returning incorrect value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

if I run the following:

```
App\User::selectRaw('country as id, COUNT(*) as value')->groupBy('country')->get()
```

I get the correct output:

```
all: [ App\User {#705 id: "UK", value: 2,},],}
```

However when I run

```
App\User::selectRaw('country as id, COUNT(*) as value')->groupBy('country')->get()->toJSON()
```

it seems to flip the id value to 0:

```
[{"id":0, "value":2}]
```

now what's interesting is if I convert it so that I don't alias the country field I get the correct output:

```
[{"country":"UK", "value":2}]
```

I need to have the field returned as id but can't seem to work out why it's doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `toJson()` on the model, if the `$incrementing` property is `true`, Laravel will automatically attempt to cast the `$primaryKey` field to the `$keyType` type. If you have not overridden any of these values, that means the `id` field will get cast to an `int` during the json generation.

In your select, you named your `country` field as `id`, so when you generate the json, it attempts to cast this value (`UK`) to an `int`, which of course is 0.

You can change your select statement to not name the field `id`, or you can work around this functionality in a ton of different ways, either modifying model properties before and after the call to `toJson()`, or by overriding the `getCasts()` method to avoid this functionality altogether.

#### Edit

Without knowing your codebase or your use cases, I would say the most flexible solution for you would be to add a new method to your `App\User` model, something like:

```
public function toJsonCustom($options = 0)
{
    $incrementing = $this->getIncrementing();

    $this->setIncrementing(false);

    $json = $this->toJson($options);

    $this->setIncrementing($incrementing);

    return $json;
}
```

Then, you call your custom toJson method instead of the original one:

```
App\User::selectRaw('country as id, COUNT(*) as value')
    ->groupBy('country')
    ->get()
    ->toJsonCustom();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm currently running str_replace on the jsonified string. Are you able to point me towards a decent tutorial on either of the methods you suggest?

Comment: Found a decent example, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @Byakku No, not really. I just took a quick look at the Laravel source code to see what the model is doing. I have updated my code with an example solution for you. But really, it is just one of many different ways of tackling this.